# Finding a Householder matrix for row elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to find a Householder matrix such that I could apply it from the right side of a matrix and eliminate values along a row. For example, I have a matrix of the form

B =  \begin{bmatrix}
    * & * & * & * & *\\
    * & * & * & * & *\\
    * & * & * & * & *\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & * & *\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & *
  \end{bmatrix}

where * represents some number. How do I find a Householder matrix, Z, such that when I multiply [B][Z] it will eliminate the numbers in the (3,1) and (3,2) spots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the vector $a=(a_{3,1}, a_{3,2}, a_{3,3},0,0)$ and the third canonical basis vector $e=(0,0,1,0,0)$ and construct the angle bisector 
$$
v=\|a\|\,e+\operatorname{sign}^+(a_{33}) a
$$
between them. The Householder reflector is then as usual 
$$
Z=I-2\frac{v^Tv}{vv^T},
$$ 
remember that $v$ and all other here are row vectors.

Comment: Awesome thanks! It turns out I was forgetting to change the basis vector e